# Sprite animation optimization in unity3d

Tags: android, ios, animation, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm currently developing a game, the Main scene in my game is a character with an animator containing about 8 animation state , each state have like minimum 100 frame and Max 180 frame , and a health bar with an animator having 3 state , as my game start i can see the amount of delay and the slow of my game ,and when i switch to another scene and go back again to my game scene, the application either take a lot of time to load the game scene again `Application.LoadLevel("Game")`, or it crash immediately , even if the assets are a `16px png file` , i am looking for some tips to make my game better and prevent that crash from the load of those huge animators .

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the sprites as separate files? If yes you should combine them in to a large png file and use the *Sprite Editor* tool to *Slice* the frames. The less files you need to load the better.

If this doesn't help you might need to lower the quality of the images. Remember to set up correct max size for your sprites and format which you want to use.

Comment: yes my sprites are in separate files should i use Tield or texture packer to do this ?

Comment: There are number of ways to do it. You can search for sprite sheet generator online. To give you an example here is one html5 based sprite sheet generator: [http://draeton.github.io/stitches/](http://draeton.github.io/stitches/)